# relation using BELONGS_TO with user table

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to join my `comment` table with my `user` table like this `comment.userId=user.id`

unfortunately when i `print_r($this->user);` i get nothing. what am i doing wrong here?

in my comment model

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, $this->module->user, 'userId'),
        );
    }

   public function getLastName()
    {
        print_r($this->user);
        die;
        return is_null($this->user) ? '' : $this->user->{$this->module->lastNameAttribute};
    }
```

where

```
$this->module->user = 'User'; //User is the model name
```

and

```
$this->module->lastNameAttribute = 'last_name';
```

in my view

```
$comments = $model->getCommentDataProvider();

$comments->setPagination(false);

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$comments,
    'itemView'=>'application.modules.comment.views.comment._view', //view file location
    'emptyText' => '<div class="alert alert-info">No comments yet.</div>',
    'summaryText' => '<h4>'.Yii::t('commentTitle','{n} comment|{n} comments',$comments->totalItemCount).'</h4>'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a small typo, maybe you mistaken while making a post:

```
comment.userid=user.id
```

here it's `userid` and in relation you referenced it with `userId`

check it out please

**EDIT - after question edit**

I'm not familiar with CommentableBehavior but it seems to me that you need to eager load User model with each Comment:

```
$comments = Yii::createComponent($this->module->commentModelClass)->with('user')->findAll($this->getCommentCriteria());
```

I added `with('user')` in `getComments()` method

Comment: you mean post the whole comment model class here?

Comment: no, just the part where you load Comment from db, I guess it's in your controller, something like comment=Comment::model()->findByPk($id)

Comment: bah, never mind. figure it out. was missing my findbyPK, did `$comment = new Comment;` instead. my bad

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you figured it out